# Ratio & Proportion Problem

Tags: ratio

$\frac{Px}{(b-c)} = \frac{Qy}{(c-a)} = \frac{Rz}{(a-b)}$

**Find the value of $(P*a*x) + (Q*b*y) + (R*c*z)$**

This question is a problem of my Class VII textbook and no solved examples of the type are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Set each ratio $=k$

and put the values of $Px$ etc. in $Pax + Qby +Rcz$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya, $Px=k(b-c)$  right?

Comment: Still don't get it

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya, What is $$P\cdot a\cdot x?$$

Comment: Can you please explain this to by imagining that you are dealing with a 10 year old.

Comment: @IabBhattacharjee Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya, Can you please go through some good tutorial of ratio & proportion

Comment: Just for some closure, I was actually 12 when I asked the question. I get the solution now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

let Px/(b−c)=Qy/(c−a)=Rz/(a−b)= k
such that Px = k(b-c), Qy = k (c-a) , Rz = k(a-b)
So (P∗a∗x)+(Q∗b∗y)+(R∗c∗z)= ka*k(b-c) + kb*k (c-a) + kc*k(a-b) = 0